# Unable to inverse column selection by cell loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am unable to inverse column selection I'm receiving error 424 Object required.

Code works fine with manual selection such as this
`Set MyRange = Selection`

```
Sub Text2Numb()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim MyCell As Range
    Set MyRange = Range("A:M").Select
    For Each cell In MyRange
        If cell.Value > 0 Then
            cell.Value = -cell.Value
        Else
            cell.Value = -cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

> Runtime Error 424
>   Object required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way to inverse the value in the cell:

```
cell.Value = cell.Value * -1
```

There is additional logic, making sure the cell is a numeric one - `IsNumeric(myCell)`.

```
Sub ReverseNumbers()

    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Set myRange = ws.Range("A1:A5")
    For Each myCell In myRange
        If IsNumeric(myCell) Then
            If myCell.Value <> 0 Then
                myCell.Value = myCell.Value * -1
            End If
        End If
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

Additionally, consider avoiding `ActiveSheet` and `Select` - [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Sorry I am now getting Runtime Error 13 Type mismatch

Comment: @Alvi - I have added the `IsNumeric()` logic, it should work.